# Push Notifications in iOS Xcode 12.4 SwiftUI App : didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken -> Never get called

Tags: swiftui, push-notification, appdelegate, xcode12

I have been searching a lot for this.  I am using a pure swiftUI App that doesn't have the classic AppDelegate.

I have been creating a manual appDelegate to install Firebase and it has worked like a charm for long time.  I recently added notifications support and I am having a problem.  The notification approval process works just fine and I have been able to send notifications on simulator, but when trying to send push notification on a real device I need the tokenID and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken seems to never being called even if I get the print confirmation that I successfully registered.

Please Help.  Been trying a lot of Wifi on/off etc..  It seems difficult to implement this in pure SwiftUI app with no dedicated AppDelegate section.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@main
struct KidBooksApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            let viewModel = AppViewModel()
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: transitionTime())) {
                //TextComposeView()
                //ImageChooserView()
                ContentView()
                    .transition(.fly)
                    //.transition(.fly)
                    .environmentObject(viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        registerForPushNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
                    deviceToken: Data) {
        print("test success")
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }
    
    func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error
    ) {
      print("test error")
      print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }
    
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
          .requestAuthorization(
            options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { [self] granted, _ in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
          }
    }
    
    func getNotificationSettings() {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            print("Registered: \(UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)")
        }

      }
    }
    
    

}
```

/*
DEBUG CONSOLE PRINT :

Permission granted: true
Notification settings: <UNNotificationSettings: 0x16de61780; authorizationStatus: Authorized, notificationCenterSetting: Enabled, soundSetting: Enabled, badgeSetting: Enabled, lockScreenSetting: Enabled, carPlaySetting: NotSupported, announcementSetting: NotSupported, criticalAlertSetting: NotSupported, alertSetting: Enabled, alertStyle: Banner, groupingSetting: Default providesAppNotificationSettings: No>
Registered: true

*/

Comment: Hi @alex any luck on this?,
Do we have to use app delegate in SwiftUI 2+ for push notifications?, isn't there any other way

Comment: I did not find any way of bypassing an AppDelegate.  I finished by using firebase cloud messaging with specific delegate for that and I use fcmToken from firebase messaging...  It works...